# Why do screens appears compressed in Hyper-V virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have noticed what looks like compression artifacts when I use Hyper-V virtual machines. I've found one pattern that especially sticks out to me. Here is a screenshot of the pattern as it appears on my host:

[image: Pattern on host machine which displays correctly.]

I know that it's some sort of issue with the virtual machine, because taking a screenshot of the same pattern looking strange is clearly portrayed. Here is a screenshot of the pattern as it appears on any Hyper-V virtual machine:

[image: Pattern on virtual machine with displays strangely]

If it's difficult for you to see where the images differ: the pattern is a simple 4-square pattern. There shouldn't be any lines forming. If you look at the latter image, there's clear horizontal lines forming.

This is easily reproduced using free Windows virtual machines downloaded from Microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/. It is reproduced in IE (Edge), Chrome, Firefox, Windows image viewer, Paint.NET, etc. It is reproduced by connecting to the virtual machine primarily using Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection, but also via Remote Desktop with all display settings configured to their highest.

Even viewing this post in a virtual machine, displays the first image strangely.

Thankfully SO is accepting these images as PNG, so that this post isn't ruined with JPEG compression.

What's going on here? How can this be corrected? Is there any way a virtual machine can be configured to not distort the screen?

Comment: RDP will always compress. Did you try using the “Basic session” mode?

Comment: I'm looking now and don't see "basic session" mode. But also in Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection, there are no display settings besides enhanced mode. This is reproduced with and without enhanced mode.

Comment: @DanielB: RDP did not use lossy compression in the past; JPEG and H.264 are approximately a Win7/8-era addition. The client can always ask for uncompressed truecolor bitmaps if anyone wants to wait for them to load tile-by-tile...

Comment: Additional info: Image looks good in VMWare Fusion.

Comment: Another thread discussing the same thing: https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperV/comments/35du84/hyperv_displays_compression_artifacts/

Comment: This was raised 6 years ago on the linked Reddit post and people are still reporting it as a problem. I'll be grateful if someone can answer with a fix.

Comment: @TidyDev as far as I'm aware it's impossible to avoid.